# Slow speed file transfer from SSD to external HDD

Tags: 14.04, usb, ssd, external-hdd, copy

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 laptop with a SATA SSD drive. I have an 2.5 inch SATA external HDD 1TB which I use as external HDD through a USB(3.0) converter. I want to take a back up of my home folder to this external HDD but the file transfer rate I am getting is just 1 MB/sec to 3 MB/sec.

/home folder is around 27 GB. The transfer rate deteriorates even more as the copy progresses. Is there any way that I can speed this up.

Comment: How are you transferring files, via the GUI, `rsync`, etc..?  how much RAM does your system have (could affect buffer size).

Comment: Use the `Disks` app, `Benchmark Disk` option, to determine whether the slowdown is due to your internal SSD, or your external HDD. Is your external plugged into a computer USB port, or a USB hub? Is your USB3 converter a separate dongle? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: I am just using GUI to copy and paste, I also get an error at the end of the copy, I realise i have to use a command like cp or rsync. I have 8GB of Ram. I use a SATA to USB converter casing for my 2.5 inch HDD and connect it to the USB 3.0 port in my laptop. Normally it works fine. Even if i have to transfer 1 to 2 GB of data it works perfectly. Only when the data is huge, there comes the problem.

Comment: Did you do as I suggested?

Comment: Search this site for "slow copy" and see that this is typical for a slower write device than the read device. System buffers fill up, and things drag to a crawl. nocache before  the copy command at least suppresses unwanted caching on the input side and may help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

That also depends on what utility you are using.

If you are using `cp`, You may try using `rsync` or `tar | pv | tar`.

you may consider using `rsync` as it will allow you to continue the progress if it somehow gets interrupted.

Using `tar|tar` also sometimes works, though it might not work in your case. (As you are copying from SSD to HDD). To do it:-

```
tar cf - . | pv | (cd /path/to/save/location; tar xf -)
```

> Though I will definitely recommend creating a  compressed tarball for
>   creating backups.

Do this in your backup directory:

```
tar -czf backup-XX.tar.gz /home
```

and then you can extract it later using,

```
tar -xzf archive.tar.gz -C /path/to/decompress
```

Comment: I will try this out and report back.

Comment: I used rsync and it worked. But it took me atleast 10 hrs to copy 27 GB data.

Comment: @codestruggle the best thing with rsync is that if you now make changes to your data and run  it, it will only update the files that were modified.

Comment: "it will only update the files that were modified" provided you set the correct switches of course...

Comment: can you explain how the tarball backup works? Is any information potentially corrupted from the compression upon recovery?

Comment: @kevinkayaks No, No information will be corrupted on recovery, if you did not interrupt the process during compression. And the best thing is even file permissions will be retained. Tar in itself does not compress, it just archives (makes 1 file out of a tree), the gzip part compresses that tarball and makes it way smaller using a compression algorithm. Though I would like to note that gzip won't work particularly well in case of mp3 and mp4 or pictures as they are already a bit too compressed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue I was able to solve. Using a 2.5" 1TB USB 3.0 external drive transferring 600GB. Slow write speeds of about 17 MB/s. The drive was NTFS format.

I reformatted the hard drive to Ext4 from NTFS and speeds went up to 150MB/s. I suspect the Ubuntu NTFS driver, but I can't be sure.